# how to fix system.NotsupportedException moq use, trying to moq an object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to mock an object

```
_logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
_sender = new Mock<ServiceBusMessageSender>();
```

the error is thrown in this line:

```
_sender.Setup(x => x.SendMessageToQueue(It.IsAny<MyClass>(), It.IsAny<ILogger>())).ReturnsAsync(true);
```

and this is the signature of the method that I can't setup:

```
public async Task<bool> SendMessageToQueue(MyClass msg, ILogger log);
```

I don't get why this method can't be overriden.

I was not expecting to get an error,
I tried using mockbehaviour.loose, verifiable

Comment: The signature of the method doesn't have a modifier that allows it to be overridden. Why do you believe Moq's message to be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was given by @ProgrammingLlama in the comments, I added virtual to the method signature.

The problem was simple, I didn't realized that most of the examples that I looked were mocking an interface and not a class, therefore the method could be overridden, not in a class